# Замена слов php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, имеется 2 значения выводящихся из бд, при выводе в моей табличке они выводятся cafe и bar: как можно произвести замену этих слов при помощи php?

у меня получилось заменить только одно значение:

```
<?php 
function callback($bar) { 
    return (str_replace("bar", "Бар", $bar)); 
} 
ob_start("callback"); 
php ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace(array('cafe', 'bar'), array('кафе', 'бар'), $subject)
```

Comment: ругается: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in

Comment: Значит у вас версия php < 5.4. Вместо квадратных скобок используйте array()

Answer (score 3):

> -- Здравствуйте! Мне надо открутить все гайки на колесе. Одну я открутил. Как мне открутить вторую?

Во-первых, не надо использовать буфер вывода для этого. Любые замены надо проводить только для тех данных, в которых эти замены нужны. А не для всего вывода скрипта. В данном случае замены надо производить до начала вывода.
Во-вторых, не надо писать код так, как будто тебя штрафуют за каждую лишнюю строчку.

Берем переменную, в которой надо заменить одно слово на другое. И заменяем:

```
$data = str_replace("bar", "Бар", $data);
```

Если надо заменить еще несколько переменных - заменяем их точно так же.

Comment: простите меня грешного, я так и не смог разобраться с редактором, но все же проблема осталась, может потому что данные этих значений передаются массивом? вот только там смогу показать :(

http://pastebin.ru/S1jY0fYj